# How I get data from table where column existing value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where one column (SerialNo) which have values (Number and Blanks). I want to write a query to get data where column (SerialNo) has some value exist.

Comment: Sample data will be helpful and what you have tried so far put that also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
Select * From YourTable
where ISNULL(SerialNo, '') <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like following, it will be better query in terms of performance if the data type of the colum is `varchar`

```
Select * From TableName
Where SerialNo is not null and SerialNo <> ‘’
```

As per your question, you are storing numbers so the data type should be int/decimal in that case it can’t have ‘’ blank values. For this scenario you can simply write your query like following

```
Select * From TableName
    Where SerialNo is not null
```